# Java code coverage reports using(maven) JaCoCo after deploying my application on tomcat

Tags: java, groovy, maven-2, jacoco

I am facing issue while getting java code coverage reports for my web-service.

I could able to generate reports using maven JaCoCo at compile time for the unit tests only.

But My requirements are as follows:

1: I need code coverage reports for tests (not unit tests) which runs after web-service is deployed on the server.

2: These tests are nothing but the simple http requests using APIS.(just hitting the APIS of my web-service and validating its response).

3: In order to run these tests, service should be running because we are just having http requests using API to web service.

4: After running these tests we should get code coverage reports.

Following are steps that I tried:

1: Configured jacoco-maven-plugin,maven-surefire-plugin and build-helper-maven-plugin in pom.xml

2: Attached JaCoCo's agent to Maven's JVM via:

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="$MAVEN_OPTS \
-javaagent:$HOME/tools/jacocoagent0.7.5.jar=output=tcpserver,port=6300"
```

3: Started web server with "mvn jetty:run"

4: Run the tests(just http request to APIs of my web-service)

5: mvn jacoco:dump jacoco:report

6: Reports can be collected later at this location ./target/site/index.html

Actual: But It is generating the code coverage report for the unit tests which runs at compile time.

Expected: It should generate code coverage reports for the tests(http requests using API to web service) which runs when service is running.

Please let me know if I am missing something here.

Here is the snapshot of my pom.xml file:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.5.201505241946</version>
            <configuration>
             <dataFile>${basedir}/target/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                 <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                       <phase>initialize</phase>
                 <goals>
                   <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                 </goals>
                 <configuration>
                              <propertyName>jacoco.agent.argLine</propertyName>
                              <destFile>${basedir}/target/jacoco.exec</destFile>
                 </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                 <id>jacoco-report</id>
                 <phase>verify</phase>
                 <goals>
                   <goal>report</goal>
                 </goals>
               </execution>         
            </executions>
          </plugin>
            <plugin>          
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.16</version>
              <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                  <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                  <version>2.16</version>
                </dependency>
              </dependencies>
              <configuration>            
            <argLine>-javaagent:/home/user_name/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946-runtime.jar=destfile=${basedir}/target/jacoco.exec</argLine>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: You could start jetty from within JUnit tests and perform test calls there

Comment: You need to stop Tomcat instance so that it can flush code coverage data to the target destfile jacoco .exec file. Once that's done, then you can use the report generation using jacoco. OR you have to look jacoco docs on using other ways (if you dont want to stop Tomcat).